# How can i regulate volume of flash in Chromium Embedded?

Tags: flash, visual-c++, volume, audio, chromium-embedded

How can i regulate volume of flash in Chromium Embedded on Windows 7?
I've tryed Mixer API, EndPointVolume API, Mmdevice API, audio sessions etc. 
But it always regulates the wrong track (creates new one that doesn't plays a sound).